# Opportunity stage closed with 2 depending picklists - only one shows up

Tags: picklist, opportunity, dependent-picklist

I would like to specify the closed reason for opportunitys (either won or lost). Therefore I created a depending picklist "close reason" for the closed stage.

[image]

Now I want another picklist shown up under the close reason where I can specify the close reason.

Is that possible and if so how?

KR Alex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be done in two ways:

1. If Detail Close Reason will not change based on the 'Close Reason', then Add another Dependency for field Stage and Detail Close Reason and setup Detail Close Reason dependency Stage values for Closed Won Or Lost.
2. We can utilizes another functionality that is available in salesforce. Which is enabling dynamic forms for detail page and use Set Component Visibility feature to show Detail Close Reason field when stage is Closed Won or Lost (Or) based on Close Reason field values.

Note : By enabling dynamic forms any page layout change for the field change will not reflect in the UI. You must add those fields in Lighting record page also to get reflected in UI. And as like page layout for Lighting record we must set APP, Profile and Record Type assignments.

Comment: Thanks. The first suggestion doesnßt seem to work. No matter wht I do there are always only two rows in the window: The stage and the main close reason window.

But the second suggestion works like expected. 

Thanks for the help.